# How to detect a method call using BCEL byte code detector

Tags: findbugs

I have to write a detector to find out about the local variables used in the methods with a class. After doing some googling i find out that detecting local variable by name in byte code is not possible. So Now i want to flag those methods that are using a local variables with a particular name. So how do i detect a method call using BCEL?

Answer (score 0):

if the code is compiled with -g, then there is a LocalVariableTable attribute that you can query to get the parameter names.